# The degree of a foliation $\mathcal{F}$ on the complex projective plane $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: manifolds, projective-space, complex-manifolds, foliations, holomorphic-foliations

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a **Singular Holomorphic Foliation** on the **Complex Projective Plane** $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$.

It is well-known that there are too many different equivalent ways to define the *Degree* of the foliation $\mathcal{F}$.

The question is:

What is the most elegant and creative way to define the degree of the foliation $\mathcal{F}$ on the complex projective plane $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$?

Comment: I think your question is vague. But I see three different ways to define the degree: 1) The number of points where the foliation is tangent to a (general) line; 2) The degree of the polynomial coefficients of a 1-form defining the foliation; 3) And to define the degree as d if the normal bundle is O(d). Note that they give different numbers.